# C# and json data parsing

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

I have a problem on data parsing, I am using C# in Visual Studios and I need a parsing algorithm for my json file. This is the structure:

```
{
  "objects": {
    "minecraft/sounds/mob/stray/death2.ogg": {
      "hash": "d48940aeab2d4068bd157e6810406c882503a813",
      "size": 18817
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/mob/husk/step4.ogg": {
      "hash": "70a1c99c314a134027988106a3b61b15389d5f2f",
      "size": 9398
    },
    "minecraft/sounds/entity/rabbit/attack2.ogg": {
      "hash": "4b90ff3a9b1486642bc0f15da0045d83a91df82e",
      "size
```

I want to pull "minecraft/sounds/mob/stray/death2.ogg" and "hash" the data.

My C# code:

```
HttpWebRequest reqobje = WebRequest.Create(assetsurl) as HttpWebRequest;

using (HttpWebResponse response = reqobje.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    StreamReader objejsonsr = new StreamReader(objectjson);
    jsonVerisi = objejsonsr.ReadToEnd();
}

parser = JObject.Parse(jsonVerisi);
JToken job = parser["objects"];
```

Comment: Please share the error you are receiving and sample code of how you are trying to parse it. Are you using Json.net or some other library?

Comment: Okay, you have a problem.  What code have you attempted?  There are lots of examples of parsing JSON using C#.  As written, your question doesn't indicate any effort on your part.

Comment: What have you tried?  I don't see any code

Comment: im using newtonsoft

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: this isnt sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using json.net, you can deserialize the string into any object you need. The sample below is an anonymous type with dictionary so you can use the dynamic keys that are coming back:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonVerisi, new { objects =
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>() });
var objects = result.objects; // key/value;
```

This is one way you can use it (maybe even to map to your own model instead of anonymous types to make it easier to work with):

```
var objects = result.objects
    .Select(m => new
    {
        Path = m.Key,
        Hash = m.Value["hash"],
        Size = int.TryParse(m.Value["size"], out var value) ? value : 0,
    }).ToList();
var path = objects[0].Path; // Get the path of the first object
```

Comment: Just added an example to the answer. You may consider adding additional null checks for the dictionary keys if moving to a prod environment, but hopefully this gets you started!

Comment: thank you very much, I've been looking for it in a week.